# Sort ng-options by translated values

Tags: angularjs

It's really easy to have select options translated with angular-translate:

```
<select name="languageId"
  ng-options="p.id as ('LANGUAGE.'+p.id)|translate for p in Const.languages | orderBy:'name'">
```

But that way the options are sorted by their original key not their translated one.
Is there a way I can have that list ordered by their **translated** value without preparing that list ahead in the controller?

Comment: hey @hoeni, have you found a solution to this. If yes, how did you do it? I have the same problem.

Comment: No nice solution, yet :-(. I'm preparing a list ahead in the controller to keep the performance acceptable.

Comment: is my solution not working for you?

Comment: @Betty it's not perfect, as it retranslates everything everytime something changed. But still the best so far ;-)

Comment: @hoeni please check my answer that does not translates twice

Comment: I'm sorry that I can't give the answer @stefitz provided more than one vote, because it's so much simpler than all the others. It should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The easiest way that worked for me (angular 1.2.24 and angular-translate 2.14.0):

```
<select name="nationality" ng-model="person.nationality" ng-options="c.id as c.name | translate for c in Const.countries | orderBy:'name | translate' ">
```

*The credit for this goes to the writer of this comment: https://github.com/angular-translate/angular-translate/issues/1064#issuecomment-267357441*

Answer (score 4):

You could supply a predicate function to `orderBy` and have that function return the translated value. It means you also have to pass in the `$filter` service to your controller because you'd need to invoke `translate` inside your JS code.

So, to offer some code as guidance:

```
// CONTROLLER
// * Don't forget to inject the $filter service

$scope.translated = function(p) {
    return $filter('translate')('LANGUAGE.' + p.id);
}
```

And then you'd modify your `orderBy` expression:

```
... | orderBy:translated
```

I realise the suggestion seems somewhat convoluted because one translation attempt occurs within `ng-options` and then another in `orderBy`, but it should sort the `select` options as you'd expect.

Comment: how do you pass the parameter from the orderBy to translated? Because I'm trying your approach but it's not working, I also tried orderBy:translated(p). thanks

Comment: The current item is implicitly passed to your predicate function. You do not need to explicitly do so via HTML (i.e. just the function name will suffice). Just make sure your predicate function definition takes a single argument.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and I recommend using an own filter, because you don't want to mess up your controller! This is my current solution:

```
/**
 * orderByTranslated Filter
 * Sort ng-options or ng-repeat by translated values
 * @example
 *   ng-options="country as ('countries.'+country | translate) for country in countries | orderByTranslated:'countries.'"
 * @param  {Array} array
 * @param  {String} i18nKeyPrefix
 * @param  {String} objKey
 * @return {Array}
 */
app.filter('orderByTranslated', ['$translate', '$filter', function($translate, $filter) {
  return function(array, i18nKeyPrefix, objKey) {
    var result = [];
    var translated = [];
    angular.forEach(array, function(value) {
      var i18nKeySuffix = objKey ? value[objKey] : value;
      translated.push({
        key: value,
        label: $translate.instant(i18nKeyPrefix + i18nKeySuffix)
      });
    });
    angular.forEach($filter('orderBy')(translated, 'label'), function(sortedObject) {
      result.push(sortedObject.key);
    });
    return result;
  };
}]);
```

**Notice** you need to pass your i18n prefix 'LANGUAGE.' and I saw your using an object instead of a simple string array so you can use it like this:

```
<select name="languageId"
  ng-options="p.id as ('LANGUAGE.'+p.id)|translate for p in Const.languages | orderByTranslated:'LANGUAGE.':'id'">
```

Comment: I would suggest to check if objKey is undefined and use the prefix as objKey in this case. With this modification the filter can also be used without prefix.

Comment: hmm I don't understand? with this solution it works for arrays and objects

Answer (score 2):

I know it's an old question, but stumbled upon this today and here's how in this case you could solve it (only works for `Array` though):

```
<select name="languageId"
  ng-options="p.id as name=('LANGUAGE.'+p.id)|translate for p in Const.languages | orderBy:'name'">
```

The trick is to assign the translation and use this assignment to sort on.