# angular.js - oderBy on list that contains elements that have been translated

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-translate

I try to implement a way to translate a select for countries. For that I use [angular-translate](https://github.com/angular-translate/angular-translate). So what I have is a list with country-ids like that:

```
var europeanCountries = ["AL","AD","AM","AT"];
```

and a two translation files (json) to show the right translation. But now I have the problem, that I need to oder the countries by there translated names. So I have the following select tag:

```
<select ng-model="value" name="{{name}}" ng-options="c as (c | translate) for c in countries"></select>
```

So, what I need now, is something like:

```
 <select ng-model="value" name="{{name}}" ng-options="c as (c | translate) for c in countries | oderBy:'<THE TRANSLATED COUTRY>'"></select>
```

But I don't know what I need to write for the placeholder `<THE TRANSLATED COUTRY>`. Any Ideas? And is that even possible?

Thank very much in advance.

Comment: If angular translate doesn't accept an array, I would create your own filter  (i.e. translateArray) that wraps angular-translate and returns an array that you can use the standard orderBy filter against.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24909242/sort-ng-options-by-translated-values