# Order translated string array in angularjs ng-options (typescript)

Tags: arrays, angularjs, typescript

The project is written in Typescript and uses angularjs.

I have a `select` element, which I am filling out with an array of strings.

```
myArray = ['C','A','D','B']
```

these strings must be translated using the `translate` filter and the corresponding `translation.json`, which is something like

```
C = example1
A = example2
D = example3
B = example4
```

I build the select using the `ng-options` directive:

```
ng-options="item | translate for item in myArray | orderBy: 'toString()'"
```

This is ordering my array using the string values and not the translated ones, so I end up with `example2,example4,example1,example3` instead of `example1,example2,example3,example4` which is what I am currently looking for. Is there any way to do this with any angular function without having to implement a custom filter?.

Comment: Any chance of a fiddle or plunk?

Comment: One option is to create a function to return the translated value and provide that function as a predicate to the orderBy clause, but by then translation happens twice once for options and second for ordering.

Comment: A bit more search on SO, and I found this guy talking exactly about that http://stackoverflow.com/a/26460244/3131696

Comment: I already read that, creating a custom filter may work but I was asking about an inline method for doing this, kind of ´ng-options="item | translate for item in myArray | orderBy: 'item | translate'"´which doesn't work